# Python: Ternary operator syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use a ternary condition in my program as follows:

```
c = 12
(print c) if (c == 10) else (print 'c is not 10')
```

However, this raises a syntax error. What seems to be wrong here?

Comment: You can only have *expressions*, not *statements*, in a ternary expression.

Comment: BTW, in Python 3 the following works: `c = 12 ; (print (c)) if (c == 10) else (print ('c is not 10'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do it like this:

```
print c if c == 10 else 'c is not 10'
```

The parenthesis are unnecessary, and you must start with the "`print`"; Python cannot make the whole command a conditional the way Perl can.

There is no Python equivalent of Perl's:

```
print "Done!" if $done;
```

Comment: The quote was always supposed to be there. Edited my code in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

you shall do `print(c)` instead of `(print c)`

Comment: `c = 12` `print(c) if (c==10) else print('not c')` still gives `syntax error`. Its not about parenthesis as Will mentioned in his answer.